# Revit API placing detail component using PromptForFamilyInstancePlacement

Tags: c#, api, revit

I'm trying to place a detail component using `PromptForFamilyInstancePlacement`, but am having trouble properly defining the `FamilySymbol`.

Examples that I have found show how to to this using a `FilteredElementCollector`, but I am trying to define the `FamilySymbol` by name.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already loaded the Family document into the project that you are working in?  If not then you can load the family into the project using `Document.LoadFamilySymbol` or `Document.LoadFamily`.  Otherwise, to find the family symbol that you are looking for, you can use something similar to the code below:

```
UIApplication application = commandData.Application;
UIDocument uiDocument = application.ActiveUIDocument;
Document document = application.ActiveUIDocument.Document;

FilteredElementCollector familyCollector = new FilteredElementCollector(document);
familyCollector.OfClass(typeof(FamilySymbol));

FamilySymbol familySymbolToFind = null;

foreach (FamilySymbol familySymbol in familyCollector)
{
  //To search by FamilySymbol name
  if (familySymbol.Name == "[Name of FamilySymbol to find]")
    familySymbolToFind = familySymbol;
  //To search by Family name
  else if (familySymbol.Family.Name = "[Name of Family to find]")
    familySymbolToFind = familySymbol;
}

uiDocument.PromptForFamilyInstancePlacement(familySymbolToFind);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (requires System.Linq) and .NET4

```
FamilySymbol symbol = GetElements<FamilySymbol>(commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument.Document)
                          .Where(item => item.Name == "NameYouWant")
                          .First();
commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument.PromptForFamilyInstancePlacement(symbol);


    /// <summary>
    /// Get the collection of elements of the specified type.
    /// <para>The specified type must derive from Element, or you can use Element but you get everything :)</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of element to get</typeparam>
    /// <returns>The list of elements of the specified type</returns>
    public IEnumerable<T> GetElements<T>(Document document) where T : Element
    {
        FilteredElementCollector collector = new FilteredElementCollector(document);
        collector.OfClass(typeof(T));
        return collector.Cast<T>();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

They both work, even in Revit 2017.  (On the second solution, the else if line needs a `==`  instead of an `=`.)

In the second solution, I used this to make sure I had the right family name and family symbol name:

```
foreach (FamilySymbol familySymbol in familyCollector)
{
  if (familySymbol.Name == "Put your Family Name here" && familySymbol.Family.Name == "Put your Family Symbol Name here")
                        familySymbolToFind = familySymbol;
}
```